# Creating docker images on successful TeamCity build

Tags: image, azure, docker, teamcity, centos7

I'm currently trying to simulate a situation where I can make a docker image after a successful build in TeamCity. I'm using Docker Hub to store my docker images and build them. After that, I web-hooked them to Tutum (Docker Cloud) to eventually push them into Microsoft Azure.

What is the best-practice to make sure there is always a valid docker images in my repo in Docker Hub? I'm running several tests in TeamCity and want to create a Docker image when the build is successful. The TeamCity server is not running a docker host, but my project has a Dockerfile.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can put last successful artifacts on your Dockerfile with ADD command

```
ADD http://{{TeamcityUrl}}/guestAuth/repository/download/{{BuildName}}/latest.lastSuccessful/dist.zip /{{DockerFolder}}
```